# How to programmatically create a View on a node that displays SQL Query content?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, database

How can I programmtically create a View on node(s) that displays the content from a specific query?

For example I would like to display the following:

```
$args = array(':nid' => $node->nid);
$results = db_query('SELECT USER_ID FROM USER INNER JOIN node ON USER.OFFICE_ID =
  node.title AND node.nid = :nid', $args);
```

Essentially, I would like to grab the 'nid' from the current node and I would like the View to display all 'users' associated with the current node, as the query would return.

I have been able to achieve this through a custom module. But I have been requested to use Views instead.

EDIT:

I've done what Johnathan Elmore suggested and got the View to display the correct information if I manually enter the 'nid' in the 'Preview with contextual filters:' space. However, if I go to the node itself, it will not display the query content.

For example:

I have nid == 123 with url alias 'office-123', if I enter 123 in 'Preview with contextual filters:', it will display the correct query information. However, if I go to 'mysite/office-123' nothing is displayed.

How can I get this View to display when I go to the node url?

Comment: bump for edit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a View block to show on the nodes, and use a contextual filter (Content: Nid) in the View to figure out which node to reference.

Then you can display the related user (user reference field?) for that node in the block.

In case you are using pathauto to auto alias your node URL's, you can setup the Contextual Filter field (Content: Nid) to determine the Nid from the URL:

[image: contextual filter for referencing specific node]

Comment: johnathan, thanks for the help, but would you know of a way to programmatically add my sql query to a view without using the views ui? I have 200+ nodes I need to do this for and doing all of them by hand is out of the question

Comment: You should be able to use this answer to create a block which will work automatically for each nodes.  It will derive the nid from the node's URL and generate a list of users that pertain to that node.  Are you trying to programmatically *change* the view as it's genererated?  My answer basically generates a View that is works equivalent to the SQL you gave.

Comment: If I may, you seem to have a very poor understanding of what Views does, and how it does it. I think you could save yourself A LOT of hassle reading the documentation or a good tutorial about Views. It would lead you do a greater level of abstraction, and factorize your code to make it more efficient and easy to maintain and extend. That's the whole point of the API. No offence meant : if you're able to make what you did with code, you'll find it easier with Views.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore, I tried your suggest and played around with the options quite a bit, but I am unable to get the View block to work correctly. More specifically, the query seems to be empty with your options. When you say contextual filters do you mean it under 'Advanced' or do you mean the line with 'Preview with contextual filters:'?

Comment: You configure the contextual filters first under the Advanced area.  Then to test the results you enter in something into the Preview contextual filters box, otherwise the query won't run. In your case you would enter a node id or URL path to the node

Comment: @JohnathanElmore. Thanks Johnathan, I've got my query tested and working. However, I don't quite understand the last step. I have an office named '83H' with nid '447' and it has url_alias 'office-83H'. If I go to 'mysite/office-83H', my view doesn't display. Would you know what could be wrong?

Comment: If office-83H is a node, then by choosing "Content ID from URL" Views will automatically know it needs derive the Node ID from the URL.  It grabs the source URL of 'mysite/office-83H', which is node/447, and then tells the View to only display users related to node 447.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore. Johnathan, that's the exact problem I am having. My query displays properly under Views UI, but it doesn't when I go to 'mysite/office-83H'. I can confirm that office-83H is a node as it appears under the node table in the DB.

Comment: Did you place the Views block to appear in the Content region, and did you set it to appear on the correct node type?  If you did and it's still not showing, what exactly did you enter into the Contextual filter textbox in Views UI to see that it works?

Comment: @JohnathanElmore. Thank you very much I see it now. I did not actually put the 'block' through structure/blocks in the content region.

Comment: Thanks for the question, this is a good way to keep refreshed